# Вывод таблицы с помощью JS и PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Добрый день, уважаемое сообщество.
Столкнулся с проблемой, стоит задача сделать js скрипт который генерирует таблицу заполняемую датами ислучайно герериррованными данными, которые выводятся на сайт в нескольких местах местах.
Код скрипта:

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var arr_cash_per_day = [];
var cash_start = 548983;
var arr_buf = arr_cash_per_day.reverse();
var rows = 20;
var cells = 1;
var sidebar_primary = document.getElementById("sidebar-primary");
var table = document.createElement("table");

function sum(m) {
    for (var s = 0, k = m.length; k; s += m[--k]);
    return s;
}

function generate_table() {
    table.setAttribute('class', 'earn_stat');
    var tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");
    for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            var buf = curr_date--;
            if (buf == 1) {
                curr_date = 30;
            }
            if (curr_date == 29) {
                curr_month -= 1;
            }
            var cellText = document.createTextNode(curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + buf);
            cell.appendChild(cellText);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            var cell = document.createElement("td");    

            function getRandomInt(min, max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            };
            var arr_sum = getRandomInt(-5000, 30000);
            arr_cash_per_day.push(arr_sum);
            var cellText = document.createTextNode(arr_sum + '.00');
            cell.appendChild(cellText);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            var sum_buf = sum(arr_cash_per_day);
            var buf = cash_start - sum_buf;
            var cellText = document.createTextNode(buf + '.00');
            cell.appendChild(cellText);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        tableBody.appendChild(row);
    }
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    sidebar_primary.appendChild(table);
}
generate_table();
```

Скрипт я включил на нужные места страницы через

```
 <?php include('table.php'); ?>
```

Скрипт работает и выводится на страницу корректно, но проблема в том что нужно сделать что бы он обновлялся один раз в заднный период времени, а не каждый раз при обновлении страницы или переходе на другу страницу сайта. Как можно сделать что бы таблица с данными после того как скрипт сработал сохранилась, и заданный период времени отображалась с неизменными данными в ней?

Буду рад любой помощи или подсказкам в каком направлении смотреть.

П.С. Подозреваю что сделать данную задачу на PHP было бы более коректно и удобно, но на JS немного пишу, а с PHP к сожалению, пока вообще не сталкивался.

Comment: Кэш в том или ином виде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно разделить функцию `generate_table` на две:

1. Генератор данных.
2. Рендерер таблицы.

Обе они будут запускаться при старте страницы и использоваться для генерации таблицы, но в функции, которая генерирует данные, вам нужно реализовать их сохранение в [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) браузера и брать оттуда, до тех пор, пока не наступит момент их обновить.

Примерно так:

```
function generateData() {
  var shouldRegenerate = checkTime(); // проверяете, наступил ли момент перегенерации
  var data;

  if (!shouldRegenerate) {
    data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('table_data'));
  }

  if (!data || shouldRegenerate) {
    data = someData(); // здесь ваша логика генерации данных

    localStorage.setItem('table_data', JSON.stringify(data));
  }

  return data;
}

function renderTable(data) {
  // генерация таблицы и добавление её на страницу
  // здесь будет тот код, который у вас есть,
  // за исключением тех частей, что отвечают за генерацию данных
}

renderTable(generateData());
```

Comment: Сделал согласно Вашей рекомендации, работает превосходно, заодно работать с LocalStorage поучился. Спасибо!